# Ampscript use case for multiple value

Tags: ampscript

I have DE Field name "xyz" value "ABC,DEF" . I need to pullin to my email as ABC separately and DEF separately.
Please suggest how write ampscript for this

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do the [**BuildRowsetFromString**](https://ampscript.guide/buildrowsetfromstring/) function.

So you would first need to call the value from the sendable DE field.

```
SET @xyz = AttributeValue("xyz")
```

Then you would need to turn this into a rowset to separate out the two values.

```
SET @rowset = BuildRowsetFromString(@xyz,',')
```

then you would loop through each row inside of it to get the different values.

```
FOR @i=1 TO RowCount(@rowset) DO
  SET @Row(@rowset,@i)
  SET @value = Field(@Row,1)
NEXT @i
```

Putting it all together, you get:

```
SET @xyz = AttributeValue("xyz")

IF IndexOf(@xyz,',') > 0 THEN
  SET @rowset = BuildRowsetFromString(@xyz,',')
  FOR @i=1 TO RowCount(@rowset) DO
    SET @Row(@rowset,@i)
    SET @value = Field(@Row,1)
    OUTPUT(CONCAT('Loop',@i,': ',@value,'<br>'))
  NEXT @i
ENDIF
```

Which would output:

```
Loop1: ABC
Loop2: DEF
```

I used a conditional statement around the rowset to help reduce errors and better allow you to handle exceptions - e.g. if there is no comma delimited string in the value or it is empty.